# Add "show all" button to BT Content Slider module

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, overrides, module-display

I am using Joomla 3.X. I have a module which displays three news and events at a time to see next set of news and events user has to press the next button. The name of the module is "[BT Content Slider](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/bt-content-slider)". Since there may be more than 10 number of news and events I want to put a show all button which when clicked shows all the news and events together. I have managed to add a button in the module by overriding it and given a link to a new article which will show all the news and events together. But the problem is when there is a new news I have to add it in the BT Content Slider as well as in the show all article. Is there anyway so that I can add new news in the BT content Slider and the show all article  gets automatically updated with the new news which I have added in the module.?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: I am still not very clear with what exactly you are trying to achieve, but from what I see the answer is that there is not an easy way mostly because your approach is not an efficient way to handle this.

Comment: @MichaelYaeger - I think he uses an article where he displays all these "new articles" - and he asks if it's possible to auto-update this article when a new "new item" is visible in the module.

Comment: @FFrewin, correct, which is not a good solution. I'm sure he didn't know you could do it another way, like linking to tags without having to recreate any duplicate content.

Comment: @MichaelYaeger For me it's still confusing to try to read his question and visualize what exactly he is trying to do and I am not in the mood nor have the time to spend much time on it. However, If you are up to it, then make a answer to guide him through another approach to achieve what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all of your news articles are in different categories, you should tag the new articles with the tag "new". Then your "show all" button links to the "Tagged Items" menu item you create for the "new" tag. Always tag articles with "new" and remove that tag on old articles you don't want to show.